# Getting a specific person to a question via commenting?

Tags: discussion, comment

I posted a question, that refers to a [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes/35930#35930) question. In the answers there I found something that confuses me. Since I want to use the results in my own question, I'd like to draw to ones attention to my question.

Is it ok, to write a comment in one of my questions to someone how is not involved yet?
I don't to bother people and if this is not a good style, I have to think of other ways..[.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111098/19341)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, [it just ain't gonna work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). The @-notification system **cannot** be used to summon users. It is only used to indicate that your comment is directed at a certain user who is already participating.

If you really want someone's attention on your problem: send them an e-mail. But beware that doing this too often may cause the other party to start ignoring you.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to bother people with eMails.